# how to get dropped files on unitys launcher in my quickly app?

Tags: application-development

How do I get the file that i've dropped on my programms icon in the launcer in my Quiklcy programm?
I already added the mime types in my .desktop file and my programm can accept commandline variables, but when I drop a file on the icon in launcher it doesn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command in your .desktop file's `Exec` line needs to contain a `%f` or `%u`.

When you drop a file on a launcher icon that gets replaces by the file name/URL and the resulting command is run.